# jquery load do not answer on call via load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have seen a voting system on http://htmlinspiration.com/ (click in a heard)

they use:

```
$(".vote").click(function() {
    $(this).load($(this).attr('href'));
    console.log("voted");
    return false;
});
```

with this html:

```
<aside>
    <a onclick="return false" class="vote" href="http://www.dasunddas/vote.php">10</a>
</aside>
```

I tried to do that too. but without any success.
My php file is:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
echo "100";
?>
```

I do not get an answer with load. If I call the php-file direct it answers with 100.

what's wrong?

here is in addition an jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U6kHS/4/

Comment: seems to work in the fiddle, did you remember document ready when testing this on your local server ?

Comment: sorry my answer in jsfiddle is empty. (look at console) the heard must get a 100 then

Comment: How do you expect jsFiddle to find a PHP file that's on your local computer or a different domain? You have to test this on a local server with files on the same domain!

Comment: Error in console at jsfiddle: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.dasunddas.de/vote.php. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Is CORS issue

Comment: for me there is no error in dasunddas.de/vote.php. If you call them you will get a 100. please try again

Comment: without jsfiddle. Here is my file online: http://www.dasunddas.de/vote.html

Comment: @hamburger, provide correct url in dasunddas/vote.html page, its  `http://www.dasunddas/vote.php` instead of `http://www.dasunddas.de/vote.php`, similarly update question

Comment: @hamburger "I do not get an answer with load." is not very descriptive - open your browser console and tell us what do you see - The request fails? Cross origin access error? Those might cause jQuery to silently fail/cancel the request and not execute your handler.

Comment: the request do not fail. i see the correct header. the answer and the html-tag are empty

Comment: i added an error handling. please have a look on http://dasunddas.de/vote.html

Comment: In the fiddle it certainly fails, as javascript does'nt have access to other domains, what happens on your server is hard for us to know! Did you try just `href="vote.php"` in your file

Comment: hah well that's funny :) At dasunddas.de/vote.html it fails due to CORS.. but at http://www.dasunddas.de/vote.html as you link is...it's all good :)

Comment: wow that is it. I tried just href="vote.php" and it works now. good idea adeneo

Comment: @hamburger That's right, because your server doesn't enforce www.* schema, when you are visiting without is your origin is without ones and apparently CORS rules are strict on the subject.. Anyways the relative URLs are the way to go in your case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't get your problem but when I visit your jsfiddle I found following error

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

TO solve this error you need to follow the answer of [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: thats another working solution. I added: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
thx

Answer (score 0):

Remove "return false" from the script . Also you don't need onclick inside 'a' tag

Comment: If they remove `return false` then it's going to follow the link to the new page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
$(".vote").click(function() {
        $(this).load($(this).attr('href'));
        console.log("voted");
        windows.location='http://www.dasunddas/vote.php';

});


<aside>
    <a class="vote" href="#">10</a>
</aside>
```